# Fancy header in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer, fancyhdr

I would like to add a custom style to my bibliography.
With this code:

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{mybib.bib}{}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
```

I've the first page in plain style (no custom header and number on bottom), whereas other bibliography's pages use the fancy style. How can I set fancy also for the first page?

Note: I'm using `book` as document type.

Comment: Could you add a full MWE with all the relevant packages? I just had a test run and it seems that new chapters do not get the fancyheader on their first page; the bibliography, however, did get a header on its first page.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look to this complete MWE (package `filecontents`is used to include a example Bib file in the MWE, `\jobname` is a placeholder for the name of your tex file (\jobname.tex)):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{companion,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{ #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{ #1}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{ #1}}

\rfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thesubsection \rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand {\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand {\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some chapter}

\section{Section I}
\lipsum[1-8]

\subsection{Subsection for this section}
\lipsum[1-2]

\pagestyle{plain}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]
\nocite{*}

\cleardoublepage % This is new !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% new plain style
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[R]{Test}% Right header
  \fancyfoot[L]{Name Firstname - v1.0 \\  Date}% Left footer
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}% Right footer
}
\pagestyle{plain}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

See to line 56. I redefine style `plain` (see the difference to your style). So you get the first page of chapter `Bibliography with header and footer too.  But let me remark it is not a good typography ...

Please see that you don't need `bib`when calling your bibliography (line 66).

Comment: If it is possible, I would like to avoid edit plain style, 'cause I'm using it in other pages such toc, list of tables, etc.

Comment: @vdenotaris because the Bibliography is usual after TOC, list of tables etc. this would be not a problem. But you can redefine it a second time with the parameters you need after your bibliography ...